# Biztalk map logical paths

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have two schemas;

```
src.xsd
destination.xsd
```

src.xsd has 2 dates and 1 string

```
-FromDate (example: 2001-01-01)
-ToDate (example: 2002-01-01)
-Intervaltype (example: 'A long year')
```

dest.xsd has 1 string property

```
-Query
```

I would like to map this so that I achieve a concatenated string in the Query property in the destination schema, like:

```
"WHERE date1 >= 2001-01-01 AND date2 <= ToDate AND IntervalDescription = 'A long year'"
```

I've achieved this by using the "string concatenate" functoid.

The problem is that the dates are optional, and i would like to set "default" values in the mapping if none are supplied in src.xsd. In that case i would like

```
 FromDate to be the current date - 10days
```

and

```
ToDate to be de current date
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use Inline C# scripting functoid with 3 input parameters and use standard C# methods to manipulate strings.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267841(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple,

```
FromDate      -> LogicalDate -> ScriptingFunctioid -> StringConcatenate -> Destination
FromDate      ---------------->
ToDate        -> LogicalDate -> ScriptingFunctioid ->
ToDate        ---------------->
Intervaltype  -------------------------------------->
```

Comment: Note that the LogicalDate functoid doesn't guarantee that the date is in the format you expect, just that it can be parsed as a date.